# Secure Grizzly HttpServer (HTTPS)

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jersey, grizzly

Currently I Have a problem getting my Grizzly Server to run with HTTPS. I am using it in combination with Jersey.

Grizzly Version is: 2.3.23

Jersey version: 2.24.1

**Here is how I start the server:**

```
public class Main {
public static final String BASE_URI = "https://localhost:8443/api/";
private static final String KEYSTORE_LOC = "I:\\rest-api\\keystore";
//private static final String KEYSTORE_LOC = "./server.cert";
private static final String KEYSTORE_PASS= "somepw123";

public static HttpServer startServer() {

    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
            .packages("com.restapi");


    SSLContextConfigurator sslCon = new SSLContextConfigurator();

    sslCon.setKeyStoreFile(KEYSTORE_LOC);
    sslCon.setKeyStorePass(KEYSTORE_PASS);

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc, true,new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslCon).setClientMode(false).setNeedClientAuth(false));
}
```

**The keystore file was generated with keytool**:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore ./keystore -alias serverKey -dname
```

**When I try to open the URL my browser tells me**:

> localhost unexpectedly closed the connection

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the issue by adding a Truststore file as well.

Code looks like this now:

```
public class Main {
public static final String BASE_URI = "https://localhost:8443/api/";
private static final String KEYSTORE_LOC = "./keystore_server";
private static final String KEYSTORE_PASS= "keystorePass";

private static final String TRUSTSTORE_LOC = "./truststore_server";
private static final String TRUSTSTORE_PASS = "truststorePass";

private static HttpServer startServer() {

    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
            .packages("com.restapi");


    SSLContextConfigurator sslCon = new SSLContextConfigurator();

    sslCon.setKeyStoreFile(KEYSTORE_LOC);
    sslCon.setKeyStorePass(KEYSTORE_PASS);

    sslCon.setTrustStoreFile(TRUSTSTORE_LOC);
    sslCon.setTrustStorePass(TRUSTSTORE_PASS);

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc, true,new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslCon).setClientMode(false).setNeedClientAuth(false));
}
```

Key- and truststore file created with these commands:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore ./keystore_client -alias clientKey
keytool -export -alias clientKey -rfc -keystore ./keystore_client > ./client.cert
keytool -import -alias clientCert -file ./client.cert -keystore ./truststore_server

keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keystore ./keystore_server -alias serverKey
keytool -export -alias serverKey -rfc -keystore ./keystore_server > ./server.cert
keytool -import -alias serverCert -file ./server.cert -keystore ./truststore_client
```